# Differentiate chrome events driven by an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

As I understand, currently there is no native way to differentiate an event (a Chrome type one) that was executed by an extension (eg using `chrome.tabs.update` and then in `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` seeing that event was executed by an extension), correct me if I'm wrong.

Questions:

- any viable workarounds for this?
- any plans from Google team to implement this?
- if 2nd point's answer is negative, is there any sense to create a request for such a feature?

In my current project, this is quite crucial and it would make the whole flow much more fluid if I could differentiate the events (something like `isTrusted` in common js, but getting the `sender` to understand if it was my extension that sent an event would be even a better deal). The setup requires listening to every possible event related to tabs, which makes it near impossible to provide a workaround based on user action timestamp or something like that. In general, I think this would be a useful feature in any case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no way, generally. As for downvotes I guess it's probably because you didn't show current code and didn't explain why it's crucial, what's fluid, etc.

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but your question seems like opinion: "should I request this feature", "would it be sueful to" etc... StackOverflow is about coding help, not feature request opinions. If you want those, post a feature request and watch the open source community do its thing with your request. Second, "any workaround" is just asking us to do the work. What have you tried? In short, thats usually what gets frowned upon here.

Comment: To be more to the point though, knowing what extension would be doing to your page would probably defeat the purpose of extensions a bit. They're doing things you aren't doing on your own page, so in all likelihood the only reason you would like to know is to detect and block them. The only thing you will know is browser events from the user, and anything an extension explicitly shares with you (they usually don't). At most you will know if the event originated from the user or is synthetic (`.isTrusted`).

Comment: @wOxxOm gotcha, thanks. Thought the provided simple example would be enough. My extension would utilize this functionality in a lot of ways and places, so I just needed a general yes/no and some advice on top regarding requesting it from Google team, etc.

Comment: @somethinghere I've built hundreds of extensions, I can understand their purpose quite well, in a big variety of different cases. In this particular case, there is an overlap, because extension view can both trigger tab events as well as it listens to them (so they can happen either by utilizing the extension itself or by using a browser naturally, while the extension view will remain open to detect the changes and change ui accordingly). That creates a problem where I cannot identify the event nature. I can think on some workarounds, but nothing ideal - all with certain gaps or edge cases.